# Bad value number for attribute value on element input

Tags: html

I am getting this error "Bad value number for attribute value on element input: Expected a minus sign or a digit but saw n instead" for this HTML code  `<label for='Card_Number'>Card Number:</label> <input type='number' id='Card_Number' name='Input_card_number' value='number' placeholder='0000-0000-0000-0000'>`. Please how do i go about this?

Comment: Value attribute must contain a number. Your value is "number" string.

Comment: Thank you @GrayFox. My code is without errors now.

Answer (score 1):

You have an input with `type=number` but then you set the value to a string, here: `value=number`. I believe what you want to do is:

```html
<label ...>...</label>
<input type='text' id'Card_Number' ... placeholder='0000-0000-0000-0000' />
```

and then think about using [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) or have type number, but then no `-` in your input

Comment: Yes. Thanks......